# Prove: if $a\cdot b = 0$ then, $a =0$ or $b =0$ or $a=b = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, solution-verification, inverse

> $a$ and $b$ are any 2 numbers. Prove that if $a\cdot b = 0$ then, $a =0$ or $b =0$ or $a=b = 0$.

I have proved it  when  $a = 0$ and $b\ne0$ or $b = 0$ and $a\ne0$ using inverse property:

> $a\cdot b = 0\\ 
> \Rightarrow a\cdot b \cdot a^{-1} = 0 \cdot a^{-1} \\
> \Rightarrow(a\cdot a^{-1})\cdot b = 0 \\
> \Rightarrow 1\cdot b = 0 \\
> \Rightarrow b= 0 $

But this solution doesn't work if $a\ne 0$ because if $a = 0$ then $0\cdot 0^{-1}$ is undefined.
However, the equation is true when $b=a= 0$ so, what is the right solution?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Also, if $a=0$ then the conclusion already holds.

Comment: a and b is any number

Comment: Are you talking about real numbers, complex numbers, integers, rational numbers (for which this is true)? But if you were talking about integers modulo $6$, for example, you would have $2\times 3=0$ (because $6=0$ modulo $6$). So you have to use a specific property of the number system (eg order) in the proof, and for this reason it is important to say what that system is.

Comment: Of course, to add to previous, the complex numbers are not ordered but you can use the properties of the modulus for this if you have already proved it for the real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a$ and $b$ are both not $0$. Thus, $d = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ exists and if $ab = 0$, then $1 = abd = 0\cdot d = 0$, a contradiction.